# Android Eclipse project - Share to Ubuntu from Windows in SVN and Import back broke the structure

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I have shared an android project from Windows Machine to Ubuntu SVN. I have checked in all files except bin folder. Then I have tried importing them back from the Import SVN projects menu into eclipse in another machine. The project structure looks completely broken with 100's of errors. But  When I synchronize my original project to SCN it shows no uncommitted changes. [image]

Please help me to identify what went wrong. Eclipse version is Juno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new line symbol in Unix and Windows system are different. You must check in project preferences, which you prefer to use:

[image]

Also, the problem may be in encoding, check what you are using now, or set it manually on the same project preferences to UTF-8.